# Include key/value pairs and single values in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a nested attribute form which includes the fields:

- nest[attr1][]
- nest[attr2][]
- nest[attr3]

*(notice the third attribute is not an array)*

In my controller, the strong params are as written:

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(
  :somevalue,
  nests_attributes: {
    attr1: [],
    attr2: [],
    :attr3
  }
)
```

This, of course, does not work because `attr1` and `attr2` are using key/value pairs to establish the array, while `attr3` is a single value permitted.

How can I use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this params:

```
{"campaign"=>{"somevalue"=>1, "nest"=>{"attr1"=>[1, 2, 3], "attr2"=>[1, 3, 4], "attr3"=>3}}}
```

You can do this:

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(
  :somevalue,
  nest: [:attr3, attr1: [], attr2: []]
)
```

You might find it weird to see `[]` with `attr1: []` inside but it's totally valid syntax in Ruby. It will be interpreted as:

```
[:attr3, {:attr1=>[], :attr2=>[]}]
```